# How do I make my keyboard popup more fluent with my view controller appearing modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

I want the keyboard to slide up as the view controller slides up. But for one of my view controllers that I present modally, the keyboard appears instantly when the view controller is presented, so the keyboard appears then the view controller slides up from under it, causing an ugly effect.

Oddly enough, this instantaneous behaviour happens when it's in `viewDidLoad`, but having it there works fine for another view controller. (But in the instantaneous one it appears for a UITextField, while the proper one is for a UITextView.)

Here's what the code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.URLTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

How do I make it present alongside the view controller? I don't have to do an ugly `dispatch_after` do I?

Comment: Try it at `viewWillAppear`, but I would guess the best you'll get easily is from `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: There's a delay with viewDidAppear, and with viewWillAppear the same result as viewDidLoad occurs.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you see with viewWillAppear -- it looks like the new view controller and the keyboard slide up together. Looks good to me.

Comment: If you can't get it right, a work-around might be roll your own presentation after a fixed delay.

Answer (score 0):

If it's loading too quickly with some methods (ViewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear) and too slowly with others you could try doing something in the middle.

I wouldn't suggest it as I'm sure theres a way to have it do what you like but I imagine that in viewDidLoad you can set the view up to respond to to keyboardWillShow and then become first responder and in the notification delay for a few milliseconds